# Implementación de USE INDEX en Query con LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, refactoring

Hola he creado un query para traer varios registros; el query funciona correctamente pero demora en extraer los datos y me he decidido por implementar índices, utilizo php para pasar la variable `$prod_code_list` este es el query:

Adjunto la consulta completa: https://pastebin.com/Yqx7qF67

Ejemplo mínimo:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Master_Producto
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Producto_Estructura
) AS Producto_Estructura
ON
    (
        Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF
    )
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Producto_Proveedor
) AS Producto_Proveedor
ON
    (
        Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF
    )
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Producto_Precio
    ORDER BY
        Prod_DateUpd
    DESC
) AS Producto_Precio
ON
    (
        Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF
    )
WHERE
    Master_Producto.Prod_Code IN('" . $prod_code_list . "')
ORDER BY
    Master_Producto.Prod_Code ASC;
```

para una consulta sin left join uso esto:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Master_Producto USE INDEX(xProd_Code)
WHERE
    Prod_Code = '00277'
```

Ejemplo de la estructura de la Tabla Master; las otras tablas relacionadas tiene una estructura similar en cuanto a índices se manejan los mismos nombre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en este caso no uso la notación directa si no que uso la notación por tabla: `Master_Producto.Prod_Code` en este caso como se accede a los indices???

Comment: Una curiosidad ¿por que los joins son contra subconsultas y no directamente con las tablas mismas?

Comment: Una de tus subconsultas, ahora que lo miro bien, tiene un ORDER, sería posible que el motor estuviera resolviendo el ORDER innecesariamente y eso tenga una penalidad en tu consulta?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho **los joins son contra subconsultas** así me la dieron XD yo estoy investigando XD y aprendiendo...

Comment: @PatricioMoracho **ORDER innecesariamente** el orden es necesario ... se quiere obtener el resultado en el orden especifico de los Prod_Code de forma ascendente... el Prod_Code no es el PK por eso pueden estar desordenados ...

Comment: Hablo del order en la subconsulta que haces contra Producto_Precio que es inenecesario por que tenes un order by final

Comment: ese creo que es para extraer el primer Precio que se encuentre en orden de la fecha ... pueden haber varios...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132109/discussion-between-patricio-moracho-and-arcanis-the-omnipotent).